# How can I read data from all data sources using google fit android sdk?

Tags: android, google-api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I need help understanding the documentation. I am developing an android application. Aim of my application is to show user total number of steps he/she has taken over last n days. These steps would include any step_count that user has synced to google fit store using a wearable or from multiple mobile pedometers.

I am trying to use android sdk with history api for retrieving data from google fit store. 
However it seems like I am not fetching all the data. I am only able to get step_count for users current mobile pedometer.

To further clarify here is example use case:
For example **App A**: Syncs 10 steps to google fit store for time T1 to T2
**App B**: Syncs another 10 steps to google fit store T2 to T3
Using **App C**: In my app I want to show total steps for time T1 to T3 ?

does fit android sdk allows to fetch all the steps user has performed ? Or does it only provide the steps that are relevant to users current device ?

For further reference here is the code I am using to fetch user's data.

```
fun getReadDataRequestBuilderAggregated(startDate: Date, endDate: Date): DataReadRequest? {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.time = startDate.setDayStartTime()
        var startTime = cal.timeInMillis
        cal.time = endDate
        var endTime = cal.timeInMillis
        return if (startTime>endTime) {
            null
        } else {

            return DataReadRequest.Builder()
                    .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                    .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                    .bucketByTime(TIME_PERIOD_GROUP_DATA_DAYS, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                    .enableServerQueries()
                    .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I did not added subscription to specific data type as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#read_data). It is necessary to add subscription if you want to read data from fitness store. As creating this subscription will sync data recorded from your source as well retrieve data from other sources.